# How to Use NFC Tag ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED Main activty?

Tags: android, nfc

I am new Developers android .How to use this code in onCreate Main activity  When i Touch the NFC Tag read Data . I Use Flowing code for read tag ,How to change it to solve Problem?

```
in manifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="example.Ultralight"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" /> 
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" /> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="MainView"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/> 
            </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/tech_filter"/> 
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase what the problem is?

Comment: i want to touch my phone NFC tag not run my app .when When the user entered then touch NFC Tag read data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the app to act on the tag only when the app is launched, then you need to set an intent filter in your OnCreate and act on it. Something like this.

**Update:** Added code.

```
NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
private String[][] mTechLists;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fbintenthandler);

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    IntentFilter ntech2 = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter ntech3 = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {
            ntech3, ntech2,
    };

    mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { 
            NfcA.class.getName(), 
            Ndef.class.getName() } };

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    resolveIntent (intent);

} 

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    resolveIntent(intent);   
}

private void resolveIntent (Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ((NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) || 
            (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)))
    {
        Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
                .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];

        extractMessage(msg);

    }
}

private void extractMessage(NdefMessage msg) {
    byte[] array = null;
    array = msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload();
    String displaystring = convert (array);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_DisplayData);
    tv.setText(displaystring);
}

String convert(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++ i) {
        if (data[i] < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        sb.append((char) data[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: String[][]    mTechLists  = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareUltralight.class.getName() } };i use this code ,how to change it

Comment: I am not sure what you want. I have modified the mTechLists variable to add MifareUltralight also, if that is what  you are asking for.